# Extracting related data from XML using SQL

Tags: sql

I've haven't asked a question on here before so bear with me.

I need to extract some XML using SQL stored within a database field. I've never done this before so I've used various different questions on here to get this far. However the way the data is structured I can't seem to extract what I need.

The XML is in a similar format to the below (I've simplified and renamed the tags, I have no control over the XML or database structure).

```
<acc>
    <accholder>
        <startdate>10/10/15</startdate>
        <tag>item</tag>
    </accholder>
    <default>
        <bal>123</bal>
    </default>
    <accdetails>
        <balance>400</balance>
    </accdetails>
    <acchistory>
        <ah code="a"/>
        <ah code="b"/>
    </acchistory>
</acc>
<acc>
    <accholder>
        <startdate>01/02/16</startdate>
        <tag>item</tag>
    </accholder>
    <accdetails>
        <balance>50</balance>
    </accdetails>
    <acchistory>
        <ah code="d"/>
        <ah code="b"/>
    </acchistory>
</acc>
<acc>
    <accholder>
        <startdate>09/10/15</startdate>
        <tag>item</tag>
    </accholder>
    <delinquent>
        <bal>123</bal>
    </delinquent>
    <accdetails>
        <balance>90</balance>
    </accdetails>
    <acchistory>
        <ah code="a"/>
        <ah code="s"/>
    </acchistory>
</acc>
```

Basically I need it to return a row for each account with specific details from that acc e.g

```
ACC 1, accholder.startdate, accdetails.balance, acchistory.ah.@code, default.bal (not all have default), delinquent.bal (not all have delinqent)
```

I've used this method

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ID
    , i.c.value(‘(//wf:accholderdetails/wf:starddate/text()[1]’,’varchar(100)’) as startdate
    , i.c.value (‘(//wf:accdetails/wf:balance/text())[1]’,’varchar(100)’) as balance
FROM 
    TABLE T
    CROSS APPLY RESULT.nodes(‘//wf:acc’) as i(c)
WHERE 
    ID = ‘’
```

Which returns one row of related data like I want but only the first row and not any further rows of data.

Where as

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ID
    , i.c.value(‘(wf:balance/text())[1]’,’varchar(100)’) as  balance
    ,j.c.value(‘(wf:startdate/text())[1]’,’varchar(100)’) as startdate
FROM 
    TABLE t
    CROSS APPLY RESULT.nodes(‘//wf:accdetails’) as i(c)
    CROSS APPLY RESULT.nodes(‘//wf:accholder’) as j(c)
WHERE 
    ID = ‘’
```

returns all the rows of data but duplicates each item making it impossible to tell which data relates to which account.

Help would be greatly appreciated! If you need further clarification let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it for MS SQL Server?

Comment: Where does `ID` come from? Are there other columns in the table that contains the XML data? What is the structure of the table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server. Microsoft Management Studio.

Comment: ID is contained within the table but not stored as XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started

```
SELECT    
    i.c.query('(./accholder/startdate/text())') as startdate
    ,i.c.query ('(./accdetails/balance/text())') as 'default.bal'
    ,i.c.query ('(./delinquent/bal/text())') as 'delinquent.bal'
    ,COALESCE(convert(varchar(10), i.c.query('data(./acchistory/ah/@code)')),'') as 'acchistory.ah.code'
FROM 
    @myxml.nodes('//acc') as i(c)
```

it returns:

```
09/10/15    90  123 a s
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I managed to use your answer as a starting point for getting the results I wanted. Thank you :)